# macOS Notes app: zooming in on sketches made w/ iPad Pro

Tags: macos, ipad, notes.app

I created a sketch in a note (Apple's Notes app, synchronized with iCloud) using 10.5" iPad Pro running 11.0.3. When I open this note on my macbook pro running 10.13, the sketch is tiny and there are no options to zoom in (zooming with cmd+shift+. does not affect the size of the sketch).

How does one zoom on a sketch so it appears the same size/sharpness as on iPad?

[image]

Comment: I am also interested in this. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to double-click on your drawing which opens it in a new note window. In this new window you can scale image or just zoom in.

Comment: This is only working for sketches created using iOS 10 or earlier